# what is stack segment manipulation?

Tags: malware, reverse-engineering, assembly

I was trying to research about anti-debugging techniques [here](https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/367-anti-reverse-engineering-protection-techniques-to-use-before-releasing-software#p10), but i failed to make sense of what ***stack segment manipulation***'s. Could anyone have a good explanation for what it means or nice resources to read up more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually stack *selector* manipulation since the CPU is in protected or long mode, though I've never heard it being called "manipulation".

The x86 was born as a segmented architecture because it had 16-bit registers and thus a plain pointer could only address 64KiB of memory.
To overcome this limitation each address was made of two parts: a segment and an offset (both of 16 bits, but they were combined as `segment * 16 + offset` to gain a 21 bit physical address truncated to 20 bits).
The segment register where `ss`, `cs`, `ds`, `es` (and later `fs` and `gs`).

With the introduction of the 80286 Intel introduced the protected mode where the segment part was not used in the computation of the physical address but as an enriched index into one of two tables where the attribute of the memory segment, including its 24-bit base, could be found.
For this reason, these values are called *selectors*. The selectors are still held in the segment registers (which now should be called selector registers but nobody does that).
Basically, in protected mode, the semantics of the values in the registers `ss`, `cs`, and so on is changed.

Now the pointer `ss:sp` was the stack pointer, *ss* being *stack segment*.
As these are two separate registers we need two instructions to change the stack pointer (the [`lss`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_152.html) instruction was introduced later): one to change `ss` and one for `sp`.

```
mov ax, <new stack segment>   
mov ss, ax                    //1
mov sp, <new stack offset>    //2
```

This was a problem because an interrupt could be served after instruction 1 but before instruction 2 and the stack pointer would point to the new segment but the *old* offset!
So Intel made any instruction that changes `ss` mask any interrupt and any exception during the execution of the next instruction.
In the example above no interrupt or exception is served during instruction 2, so the pair acts like it's a single instruction (w.r.t. interrupts/exceptions).

This feature was inherited and it's still present today: an instruction that changes `ss` masks the interrupts/exceptions of the next instruction.
Since the #DB (debug, interrupt number 3) exception is the hardware mechanism behind single stepping and breakpoints (and any other debug feature) changing `ss` will prevent a breakpoint in the next instruction from triggering.
Likewise, single stepping would skip that next instruction.

This technique is rarely used since it is well known and skipping an instruction usually doesn't affect the control over the debuggee but you must be careful not to use a breakpoint after a stack segment manipulation if it's the only thing that's preventing the debuggee from running free.